# "Tile photos" or "photos for tiles"?

Tags: word-usage

Let's suppose that I want to tile a floor and every tile will have a photo printed on it. I have to select the photos by myself. What would be the more correct way to refer to these photos:

- photos for tiles

or

- tile photos

?

Comment: The "noun attribute" usage works better when the particular combination refers to something reasonably well-known (a ***milk bottle***, or a ***car radio***, say). Because not everyone will be familiar with the concept of "a photo only intended to be transferred onto the surface of a [ceramic?] tile", you should probably avoid ***tile photo*** and stick with the preposition-based form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having photos printed on floor tiles is far too niche to have an idiomatic name or phrase to refer to them, but if you were discussing them with someone who already knew about your plan to have photos printed on tiles, you could probably refer to them as anything and they would understand.

To be grammatically correct your examples would need an article, ie '*the tile photos*', or 'photos for *the* tiles'. This is because the photos are not exclusively for use on the tiles, they are photos you already have, but you are referring to them in connection with a specific purpose.